# How to remove space after using remove() function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making reminder app here is the interface

[image]

Now when i click the "All Checked" button all the check boxes removes. I'm using `remove()` function for that but after removing these check boxes the space remains there, and when I'm putting the new value it's coming after that space. I was trying trim function but its not working

MY HTML

```
  <div class="has-success topSpaceFromRoof">
     <div class="checkbox">

     </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-block slight" id="allFinished">
     ALL Checked
  </button>
```

MY JAVASCRIPT

```
  $('#allFinished').click(function(){
    $('span').remove();
    $('.checkbox').trim();
  });
```

MY JAVASCRIPT FOR INPUT VALUES

```
 $('<label><span>' +
            '<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxSuccess" value="option1">' +
                 input.val().toUpperCase() +
                    '</span></label><br/>').appendTo('.checkbox');
                     event.preventDefault();
```

Looks Like This

[image]

Comment: I guess the `label` and `br` tags are still there, cause you're only removing the `span` tag. Be careful though, cause you are removing all  `span` tags on the whole page.

Comment: try using $(".checkbox").hide()

Comment: think about your markup, especially the elements you want to add or hide. they should be hidden / added / removed completely, not only one part of it. (use a div around every checkbox item as a wrapper and remove / add this div)

Comment: Please try out my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
$('#allFinished').click(function(){
   $('span').remove();
   $('.checkbox').html('');
});
```

Another option you can use by using some CSS like,

```
.checkbox label{
    display:inline-block;
    margin:2px 0;
}
```

And no need to add `<br/>` after your `dynamically added label's`.

And some jquery code like,

```
$('#allFinished').click(function(){
   $('.checkbox label').remove();
});
```

Comment: only because something could work, doesn't mean you should use it...thats like closing a broken window with a sheet of paper.

Comment: I would suggest a solution which does not remove all `span` tags from the whole page.

Comment: just because SO is full of these "types" of answers, doesnt make it legit to post it, right? this is just bad practice. not only bad practice, its heavily error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

**Please try this :**

Use `.empty();` method

```
$('#allFinished').click(function(){
    $('span').empty();
});
```

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_empty.asp)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/ujeu8jj4/2/)

Comment: So this empties all `span` tags on the page? Could work, but not a great suggestion. Besides it leaves all `label` and `br` tags [for every entry] intact. Which is the problem in the first place.

Comment: @vonUbisch I wrote the code based on the question asked. In the question he also used $('span') as the selector. I did not get why its not a good suggestion? Please check my demo. In that a <p> is used inside the <div> . When <div> is emptied <p> is also removed.

Comment: His code produces a `label`, `span` and a `br` tag. You need to remove them all to solve the problem. You are only removing `span` and to make it worse, you (and almost all other answers) are removing ALL `span` tags that will be on that page. While your answer might work, it's definitely not a good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#allFinished').click(function(){
    $('.checkbox').find('*').remove();
    // $('.checkbox').empty();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need to code

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/rqbbL2er/3/)

**HTML**

```
<input type=text />
<input type=button value=Submit />
<div class="has-success topSpaceFromRoof">
     <div class="checkbox">

     </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-block slight" id="allFinished">
     ALL Checked
  </button>
```

**CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#allFinished').click(function(){
        $('span').remove();
        $('.checkbox').empty();
      });

    $(":button[value=Submit]").click(function(){
        var input=$(":text");
        $('<label><span>' + '<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxSuccess" value="option1">' + input.val().toUpperCase() +                        '</span></label><br/>').appendTo('.checkbox');

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about your markup first. Try to come up with a structure which allows you identify a whole block of your checkboxes with its label, the input itself and whatever element you want to associate with this checkbox.

Something like this:

```
<div class="checkbox-wrapper">
     <label>
           Blablub
           <input type="checkbox" value="1" />
     </label>
</div>
```

Now in your click event you could loop through all your checkboxes (elements with your identifiying class `checkbox-wrapper`) and remove the whole element if its checkbox is checked:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#allFinished').on("click", function(){
        $(".checkbox-wrapper").each(function(){           
             if($(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked")){
                   $(this).remove();
              }
         });
    });
});
```

Working Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/n1o3t3nz/1/